# flask_socketio - Use nginx to serve static content and websockets on the same port

Tags: nginx, websocket, flask-socketio

I'm running a flask_socketio server using gunicorn and eventlet behind nginx.

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
daemon off;
worker_processes  auto;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /docker/app/public;

        location / {
            # Return the file if found, otherwise goto the @websocket location
            try_files $uri @websocket;
        }

        location @websocket {
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        }
    }
}`
```

There are two problems with this configuration.

1. Accessing http://serverip/ returns 404, but http://serverip/index.html works as expected.
2. The websocket connection fails with

   Error ​ WebSocket connection to 'ws://serverip/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=bvsTNP3zXgW_DNBGAAAC' failed: Stack table collapsed

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: What is `@websocket`? Also, have you seen the Flask-SocketIO documentation on how to use nginx? https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html#using-nginx-as-a-websocket-reverse-proxy

Comment: The idea is that the python app is only a websocket server. The HTML, JS, etc is all static, so should be handled by nginx? @websocket is a named location.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Never seen this pattern where the websocket connection is the failover from static files. I don't think I would do it this way even if it worked, but in any case, as I said above, the documentation has a working nginx configuration if you want to start from something reliable.